# Export Eclipse Plugin Jar through command Line is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I have tried to export one eclipse plugin Using below steps.

Step 1: Open Eclipse -->Export --> Plugin development --> Deployble Plugin and fragments.

Step 2 : Put Destination Directory and on option mark save as ant script.

Step 3 : After Finish plugin jar has been created successfully from GUI and create one build.xml . build.xml output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="plugin_export" name="build">
<target name="plugin_export">
<pde.exportPlugins destination="C:\Build" exportSource="false"      exportType="directory" plugins="com.user.plugin" useJARFormat="true"/>
</target>
</project>
```

Step 4: Copy build.xml into eclipse dir and use below command line to execute the build.

```
    eclipsec.exe -noSplash -data "C:\Workspace" -application    org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -Debug
```

No error getting on console. But Jar not created on 'C:\Build' location.

**NOTE : This project has plug-in target platform set for some dependency jar is required to build the project. 
1 .IS that is the problem? 
2 .How to pass Target platform command during exporting eclipse plugin ?**

When I check this step with sample project this is working fine . But only for above project this is not working.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
Deb

Answer (score 0):

`pde.exportPlugins` runs asynchronously (that is it just starts the export process) this make it more or less impossible to use in a headless ant script like yours.

Eclipse bug [58413](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=58413) describes this and is marked 'won't fix'

Comment: Thanks for your response. but sir any way to achive to build and export eclipse pluin jar file through CLI.

Comment: I believe you can use Eclipse Tycho with Maven to do this, but it is not something I use.

Comment: Thanks once again sir. When we do Export from Eclipse in back-end it generate ant script and export plugin jar file. So same project will work with Tycho and maven combination.